# WCF performance transferring List of objects using wsHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to reduce the time taken to send a list of DTO objects over the internet using wsHttpBinding.  Security is TransportWithMessageCredential with an X509 certificate.  The time is about 2.5s for 500 objects in a list, using basicHttpBinding with no security only saves a few milliseconds.

Changing messageEncoding to Mtom seemed to slow it down further.  I had added tracing and viewed files using svcTraceViewer and the longest time shown was after the message was sent there was an activity boundary then "The server security session received a close message from the client" which was 1.5 seconds, the transfer seemed only to take 400ms.

I have added the following Context and Concurrency attributes to the service class

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

In the DTO classes, I have added name to the data member to reduce time de-serializing

```
  [Serializable]
[DataContract(Name="Sample")]
public class Sample
{
    [DataMember(Name="Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

In the service Web.Config file the behavior is

```
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="300" maxConcurrentSessions="5000"  maxConcurrentInstances="300" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Client Web.Config has binding of

```
   <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyEndpoint" 
             closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
             openTimeout="00:01:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
             transactionFlow="false" 
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             messageEncoding="Mtom" 
             textEncoding="utf-8"
             useDefaultWebProxy="false"
             allowCookies="false"  >
      <readerQuotas 
            maxDepth="2147483647" 
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <reliableSession 
            ordered="true" 
            inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport 
            clientCredentialType="None"  />
        <message 
            clientCredentialType="Certificate"  />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

and behavior setting

```
 <behavior name="MyBehavior">
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
              <clientCredentials>
                  <clientCertificate findValue="xxxxxxx" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
              </clientCredentials>
          </behavior>
```

Is there any suggestions how to get this to be fast and scalable?

**SOLUTION**
It turns out that gzip wasn't actually installed in IIS as we had assumed.  I will definitely be testing Marc Gravell's protobuf-net for production, however gzip solved the immediate problem.

Comment: How big are the objects - how much data comes over the wire - and is this local or remote? How remote are the users?

Comment: This is over the internet windows 2008 r2 server iis 7 both client and server.  I haven't measured the data size, would fiddler be best for this? Object is 18 string and int fields, each object is about 900 characters in the message xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pobably benefit a lot from using GZip compression.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [PROTOBUF](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/): [Protocols Buffers Test](http://csharptest.net/category/projects/protocol-buffers/)

You also have a .net version : [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)

Answer (score 1):

Bandwidth time and serialization/deserialization time may be a factor here. Also, transport-security time will be roughly related to bandwidth size. I suggest one thing you could look at here would be reducing the bandwidth time. Disclaimer: I'm the author (but I'm not selling anything; 'tis all free/OSS) - but: protobuf-net uses a **much** denser data format than `DataContractSerializer`, and has hooks to attach to WCF to swap the serializer. When using this you *would* ideally want MTOM enabled, as it is binary. This can be done either explicitly or [via configuration](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/11/controlling-wcf-protobuf-net-at.html). Note that it works simplest if the two ends are using assembly sharing; if you are using "mex" to generate the client half, some extra steps may be involved.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll give protobuf-net a go.  I am probably using mex but I control both ends so will look at assembly sharing.

Comment: @Paul I can't guarantee that it'll help every single scenario, but it usually does a good job